# Receiving a no such column error in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to make individual pages for toppings in a pizza, and I received a no such column error and i'm not sure what's going on. Doing an exercise from the Python Crash Course 2nd Ed (Ch.18, Ex.8), I've tried applying migrations, I'm able to go through the pages of index and pizzas, but unable to enter the pages of each pizza which displays toppings on them, sorry if I posted any unimportant code.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topping(models.Model):
    """A pizza topping"""
    topping = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the topping."""
        return self.topping

class Pizza(models.Model):
    """A pizza type"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the pizza type"""
        return self.name
```

urls.py

```
"""Defines URL patterns for pizzas"""
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'pizzas'

urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    #Page that shows all the pizzas.
    path('pizzas/', views.pizzas, name='pizzas'),
    
    #Detail page for a single topic.
    path('pizza/<int:pizza_id>/', views.pizza, name='pizza'),
    ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Pizza

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    """The home page for pizzas."""
    return render(request, 'pizzas/index.html')

def pizzas(request):
    """Show all the pizzas"""
    pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
    context = {'pizzas': pizzas}
    return render(request, 'pizzas/pizzas.html', context)

def pizza(request, pizza_id):
    """Show all toppings on a pizza"""
    pizza = Pizza.objects.get(id=pizza_id)
    toppings = pizza.toppings.all()
    context = {'pizza': pizza, 'toppings': toppings}
    return render(request, 'pizzas/pizza.html', context)
```

base.html

```
<!--Base template/Parent template-->
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'pizzas:index' %}">Pizzeria</a> -
  <a href="{% url 'pizzas:pizzas' %}">Pizzas</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

pizza.html

```
{% extends 'pizzas/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Pizza: {{ pizza }}</p>

  <p>Toppings:</p>

  <ul>
  {% for topping in toppings %}
    <li>
        <p>{{ topping.topping }}</p>
    </li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>There are no toppings for this pizza yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: pizzas_topping.topping
[24/Jun/2021 11:20:31] "GET /pizza/2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 185486
```

traceback:

```
[24/Jun/2021 11:43:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 192
[24/Jun/2021 11:43:03] "GET /pizzas/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321
Internal Server Error: /pizza/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: pizzas_topping.topping

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\pizzas\views.py", line 21, in pizza
    return render(request, 'pizzas/pizza.html', context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\chawa\OneDrive\Desktop\pizzeria\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: pizzas_topping.topping
[24/Jun/2021 11:43:04] "GET /pizza/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 185462
```

Comment: Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I've tried that before posting, no changes were detected, are there any other important files that I should be posting?

Comment: Can you share the traceback of the error for us to see where the error is originating from?

Comment: Will do! Just added the traceback

Comment: How about `python manage.py makemigrations <name-of-app>`?

Comment: Attempted after you advised, no changes detected in the app as well.

Comment: `topping.text` won't work as the only field a Topping has is `topping`. Try `{{ topping.topping }}` in your HTML. Not sure this is your problem...

Comment: Did you add your app to the settings.py file, inside the INSTALLED_APPS list? You need to do that in order for Django to be able to detect the migrations

Comment: Yup! It was already added.
@Alejandro didn't work either.

Comment: I redid the whole project, and it managed to work. Perhaps I messed up the entries before.